# Bare metal STM32

Tags: c, gnu-make

I have a project by use STM32F103C8T6. It has tree:

```
 __main.c
|__main.h
|__led.c
|__led.h
|__stm32f1xx_startup.c
|__Makefile
```

I'm using arm-none-eabi-gcc to compile this project. `Makefile` as below:

```
CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
MARCH = cortex-m3
CFLAGS = -c -mcpu=$(MARCH) -mthumb -std=gnu11 -Wall -O0
RM = rm -rf
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
INCS = $(wildcard *.h)
all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) *.o all
```

When I run `make` command by Terminal of VS Code,it's not generate execute file and has a warning like this:

```
minh@Minh:~/Workspaces/Stm32/BeraMetal$ make
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -std=gnu11 -Wall -O0 main.c -o main.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -std=gnu11 -Wall -O0   -c -o stm32f1xx_startup.o stm32f1xx_startup.c
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -std=gnu11 -Wall -O0 led.c -o led.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -std=gnu11 -Wall -O0 main.o -o all
arm-none-eabi-gcc: warning: main.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

Please tell me how I can fix it? Thank advance.

Comment: First of all your `all` rule in the makefile will name the output file `all`. Secondly, your `all` rule will only link (when you fix the linker error) the first object file into the program `all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the same flags for both compilation into object files, as when you attempt to link the object files together.

The problem is that the linking command will then use the `-c` flags, which is used to build object files.

You need to separate compilation and linker flags. Or at least not specify `-c` in `CFLAGS`.

Answer (score 0):

> how I can fix it?

Don't pass `-c` to linking stage. Also, you have to pass all objects to the linker.

```
CFLAGS = -mcpu=$(MARCH) -mthumb -std=gnu11 -Wall -O0
all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Consider using something newer than grandpa Make - `CMake` `Scons` `Meson`.

Comment: it has an error:
`minh@Minh:~/Workspaces/Stm32/BeraMetal$ make
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -std=gnu11 -Wall -O0 -c main.c -o main.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -std=gnu11 -Wall -O0   -c -o stm32f1xx_startup.o stm32f1xx_startup.c
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -std=gnu11 -Wall -O0 -c led.c -o led.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -std=gnu11 -Wall -O0 main.o -o all
/home/minh/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-linux/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.07/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld:`

Comment: `/home/minh/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-linux/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.07/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m/nofp/libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): in function `exit':
exit.c:(.text.exit+0x16): undefined reference to `_exit'
/home/minh/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-linux/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.07/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':`

Comment: `main.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `HAL_GPIO_WritePin'
/home/minh/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-linux/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.07/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `HAL_GPIO_WritePin'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:15: all] Error 1`

Comment: `undefined reference to _exit` research what is newlib and nosys.specs and what does it do. `undefined reference to HAL_GPIO_WritePin` well, it's not like you can call any function from your code and it will work, you have to link with it. To link with STM32 HAL libraries, you have to download and compile them and link with them. Research what is undefined reference and what does it mean.